# create AWS s3 client

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Im new to AWS and would appreciate some help getting this to work on aws-sdk/client-s3 for nodejs/expressjs.

```
import {S3Client} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

const s3ClientData = ():S3Client => {
  const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  const bucketRegion = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION
  if (!accessKeyId || !secretAccessKey || !bucketRegion) return throwError(__filename, 'NOT_FOUND', 'MISSING_DATA', 'Missing AWS Credentials')

  const client = new S3Client({
    region: bucketRegion,
    credentials: {accessKeyId, secretAccessKey},
    endpoint: 'https://my-bucket-name.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com',
    forcePathStyle: true
  })

  return client
}

export default s3ClientData
```

No matter what I do I keep getting different errors

E.g.

If I try to list objects I get

```
const data = await s3ClientData().send(new ListObjectsCommand({
    Bucket: my-bucket-name,
    Prefix: `${path}/`  (the path/folder where the file is located in S3)
}))
```

Returns: The specified key does not exist

---

If I remove the endpoint as seen on many online examples, I get
`The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.`

---

If I remove forcePathStyle:true
I get `Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames:`

---

By changing the endpoint to: 'https://s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com' I get:

```
    "Code": "PermanentRedirect",
    "Endpoint": "undefined.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "Bucket": "undefined",
    "message": "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."
```

I've checked the region on the S3 console and it shows eu-north-1
I can't seem to find a way to get this working. Is there any specific configuration needed in the s3.console.aws.amazon.com?

Comment: Try removing the bucket name from your endpoint such that it's just `s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: When running your test, how is `path` defined and what is its value? Also, what is the value of `process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME`? You might consider printing both values to the console to check that they are what you expect them to be. Also, your code appears to be TypeScript rather than JavaScript and as Node.js does not run TypeScript natively, you should tag your question appropriately.